# Gray section appearing at bottom

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I am making a social network, and I'm using `linear-gradient(#dadae3, white)`. This works, however a section at the bottom with the color `#dadae3` shows at the bottom. I do not have an element for this section.

Screenshot:

[image]

I am looking for a solution to get rid of this gray section. Thanks!

Comment: That's most likely because the gradient doesn't cover the entire element, and your page's background is #dadae3. Look in your CSS for styling for elements `body` or `html`.

Comment: A fiddle or codepen would be great.

Comment: or at least some of your code !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background gradient is just repeating there because of lack of <s>[`height`](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPvLQ/1/)</s> of the `body` element(I assume you are using gradient on `body` element), also make sure you have set your `background-repeat` to `no-repeat`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPvLQ/)

```
html, body {
   height: 100%; /* Setting both the elements height to 100% */
}

body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    /* mmmm not required as we have set to fixed but than too no harm using it */
    background-attachment: fixed; /* Fixes background for you */
    background: linear-gradient(#dadae3, white);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be the `background-color` for the `body` or the `html` element of the page!

And the gradient is just covering the `div` in your page! Check the css for body or html (or the parent of this element).

You might also want to check the `footer` CSS properties too!

Try this for a check:

```
html, body, footer {
  background-color: transparent; // remove the background..
}
```